# How to use a regular expression in pandas dataframe with different records in a column?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I'm stuck with a little problem with python and regular expressions.
I got a pandas table with records with a different 
different order of construction, see below.

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|                    Total                     |
+----------------------------------------------+
| Total Price: 4 x 2 = 8                       |
| Total Price 200 Price_per_piece 10 Amount 20 |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

I want to separate the records in the ‘Total’ column to 3 other columns like below.
Do I need first to split those columns in 2 subset and to do different regular expressions or do you guys have some other solutions/ideas?

```
+-------+-----------------+--------+
| Total | Price_per_piece | Amount |
+-------+-----------------+--------+
|     8 |               4 |      2 |
|   200 |              10 |     20 |
+-------+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: You can use something like this `re.compile("(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
dtotal = ({"Total":["Total Price: 4 x 2 = 8","Total Price 200 Price_per_piece 10 Amount 20"]})
dt = pd.DataFrame(dtotal)

data = []
for item in dt['Total']:
    regex = re.findall(r"(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)",item)
    regex = (map(list,regex))
    data.append(list(map(int,list(regex)[0])))
dftotal = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Total','Price_per_piece','Amount'])
print(dftotal)
```

Output:

```
   Total  Price_per_piece  Amount
0      4                2       8
1    200               10      20
```